# Does performance and quality of watching videos on YouTube, browsing, working with office or IDE are very sensitive to size of VRAM?

Tags: graphics-cards, memory, performance, video-adapters, ryzen

Laptops with integrated AMDGPU (Vega 3, Vega 6) have different size of VRAM. Some models have dynamical automatic size that depended from size of RAM (4GB RAM - 0.5GB VRAM, 16GB RAM - 2GB VRAM etc) some models allow to change it manually. But some have fixed size, that cannot be increased.

I understand that size of VRAM is important for games. I mean about range of VRAM from 0.5GB till 2-3GB.

1. Is more VRAM is better for watching online video, browsing and other working stuff?
2. Does performance and quality of watching videos on YouTube, browsing, working with office or IDE are very sensitive to size of VRAM?

Answer (score 0):

If it is onboard graphics, forget vram, but focus more on system memory. It is shared, so if one part is full, your pc will fill the other part of your system memory.